# jq in shellscript: parse argument with '-'

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

Here's the json I need to parse:

```
{"protocol-config":[
    {"protocol":"p1","config-var1":"vc1", "config-var2":"vc2"},
    {"protocol":"p2","config-var1":"vc3", "config-var2":"vc4"}
]}
```

And my code to parse is like the following:

```
declare -a vals=("var1" "var2")
for val in "${vals[@]}"; then
    eval "result=($(cat $INPUT | jq -r --arg i "$i" --arg var "config-$val" '.protocol-config[$i | tonumber][$var]'))"
done
```

The problem is this part:

```
jq -r --arg i "$i" --arg var "config-$val" '.protocol-config[$i | tonumber][$var]'
```

I can't get the value of it and I guess the reason is that I didn't pass $var correctly? I also tried

```
jq -r --arg i "$i" --arg var "config-$val" '.protocol-config[$i | tonumber][\"$var\"]'
```

But it doesn't work..Maybe the tiny '-' in the "config-$val" made it special? So my question is what is the right way to pass in argument like "config-$val" in jq?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Instead of just saying "But it doesn't work", can you include actual and expected output? There are also seemingly unrelated problems with this code: using `then` instead of `do`, not defining `$i`, mixing `$REPLY` and `$input`. Can you fix those first? (Remember never to modify code between running and posting. Modifications should always happen before running, so that posted code and results are in sync)

Comment: You make it far too complicated. Which values do you want to extract? I'm pretty sure it can be a one liner.

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl I need to extract config-var1 and config-var2. The thing is, Maybe later I need to extract config2-var1, config2-var2, config3-var1, config3-var2 and etc. , which does not currently exists. To sum it up, '\*-var1' and '\*-var2'.

Comment: If you just want to inject a variable into the jq command, use something like this: `i=1; jq ".foobar$i" test.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command fails not because you're looping wrong or passing arguments wrong, but because `protocol-config` is not a valid identifier:

```
$ jq '.protocol-config'
error: config is not defined
```

The first step should always be to find a command that works without a loop or variables. Don't try to write a loop for something you can't get to run once! Don't generalize a command you can't get to work in a specific case!

Here's a working command to get `config-var1` from index `0`.

```
$ jq -r '.["protocol-config"][0]["config-var1"]' < json
vc1
```

Now we can try to abstract out the arguments, testing to make sure it still works:

```
$ jq -r --arg i "0" --arg var "config-var1" \
    '.["protocol-config"][$i|tonumber][$var]' < json
vc1
```

Now that we have a working way of getting single items, we can do that multiple times with a loop:

```
$ cat myscript
i=0
file="json"
for var in "var1" "var2"
do
    jq -r --arg i "$i" --arg var "config-$var" \
        '.["protocol-config"][$i|tonumber][$var]' < "$file"
done

$ bash myscript
vc1
vc2
```

Comment: Plus one for the good explanation. But shouldn't it output 4 values?. Also you might like to know that the recent version of `jq` introduces the function `startsWith()` ...

Comment: @hek2mgl Maybe. I understood the goal to be to get a predetermined variable for a specific entry. It could have been to get all "config-*" variables for all entries flattened.

Comment: yeah, maybe. (probably I just got it wrong). However that startsWith is nice, but is not part of the jq that is shipped with most distros today. but after the next updates it should be available! :P

Answer (score 0):

1. The original problem statement is unclear to me, but I suspect that there's no need to invoke jq more than once or even to use any bash scripting at all.  (jq is fast but there is some overhead in starting it up.)

Suppose, for example, that you want to pass the list of "var" values to the jq program. This can be done as illustrated by the following:

```
$ jq -n --arg x '["var2","var2"]' '$x|fromjson'
[
  "var2",
  "var2"
]
```

2. Regarding "startswith" -- the current "stable" release of jq is version 1.4, which has been available since June, 2014; it has the filter startswith/1, which has been available since December 2013.  For further information, about available downloads, see in particular:

   - http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download
   - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases